# Integrate Gitlab and TravisCi

Tags: ruby, gitlab, travis-ci

Is there a way where I can integrate TravisCi with Giltab? or at least logging in TravisCi using username and password and not Github credentials?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, as of right now, Travis-CI is strictly bound to GitHub. While there are certainly talks about lessening this requirement, it's still there for still some time to come.

As a workaround, you could push your stuff to GitHub and from there to Travis, using GitHub only as an intermediary.