# Gitlab and CI server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I recently moved a repo from bitbucket to gitlab. I now want to have a CI (travis or drone) working with my repo.

After some reading, i found out that gitlab builded their own CI (gitlab CI) but needed to be self hosted and it dont seem to be possible to set on heroku.

I dont want to manage an AWS instance only to get a CI server, as travis, drone (and probably some other that i dont know of) already exist and do the job.

Is there something i missed? Is there a way to have (quick and easy) gitlab CI (i repeat that i wont take a self-managed server for this) or i will have to move to github or get back to bitbucket?

Gitlab is really a nice product, but the lack of support for CI server is a road block!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MagnumCI](https://magnum-ci.com/) now support Gitlab and other popular platforms. Also Gitlab launched the own [CI service](https://ci.gitlab.com) with shared servers.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that Drone already does GitLab: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/5675077-integrate-docker-drone-with-gitlab-ci-runner but I haven't tried it.

You might also have a look at: https://githost.io/, it manages GitLab and / or CI for you, and you can connect the CI to any GitLab instance: https://githost.io/docs#ci_master Since you already have the CI there, keeping it in-house is not a concern, so you might as well also have the GitLab instance there or at gitlab.com It was acquired by GitLab in 2015 Q2 https://twitter.com/gitlab/status/592438051533524993

Travis on the other hand seems to be bound to GitHub and thus not an option: [Integrate Gitlab and TravisCi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693830/integrate-gitlab-and-travisci)

As mentioned by Dorum, Magnum CI also handles GitLab: https://magnum-ci.com/docs